# Gradle error after add android support design library

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

I'm getting this error after add `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'` to my gradle file:
`.../app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/res/values/values.xml` with this message `Error:(1) Attribute "insetForeground" has already been defined`.

I have this on my build.gradle file:
`

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
```

I have omitted `AppCompat Support Library` as [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) says.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might have `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` for your Navigation drawer design in your project. Remove those attribute resources in your attr and replace the drawer layout with [NavigationView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog).

Comment: And I just found that Google puts `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` right [inside the Android design support library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/internal/ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F).