# android design library gradle null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

I'm trying to add `android.support.design` library to my project: All the interesting things in my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.0'
}
```

I'm getting

```
Error:Android Gradle Build Target: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When removing `com.android.support:design:22.2.0` (and adding back `v4` and `AppCompat`), build is successful.

[image: library version]

[Another similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541403/gradle-error-after-add-android-support-design-library) didn't help me

Notice that i'm building using **Intellij 14**

Comment: Have you seen this answer? Problem is with design support library . http://stackoverflow.com/a/30557995/2091181

Comment: yes. it is not relevant. i've found the answer and posting it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the `app` using `android studio` and not `IntelliJ 14` and got a different error:

```
`Error:(1) Attribute "insetForeground" has already been defined`
```

So if someone is running `IntelliJ 14`, until next update of `Intellij 14` I guess It's safer to use `android studio 1.3.+` (or at least check for errors using `android studio`.

If one get the same error.

- go to attr.xml and remove `declare-styleable name="ScrimInsetsView"`
- using *ctrl-shift-f* search for `insetF` and remove `app:insetForeground` attribute from all the layout that contains such attribute.

Everything should work OK now

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. I guess it comes from an combination of mismatching parameters in grade and your xml resources..
Maybe this will help (for me it did):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }  
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

...

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Give the build.grade the 1.1.1, too (just in case)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Hopefully the next sync, clean and rebuild will pass (or fire a meaningful error message like 'color-res blabla not found').

Btw: From time to time my IntelliJ is setting itself to other Java-configs (e.g. Java8 with lambdas) - so "just in case": 
Don't forget to check if your project SDK is set up correctly (File > Project-structure > project > choose the SDK).