# IntelliJ Android develop, Compile error without any stacktrace, R file not generated, what should I do?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

This is a half finished project, it was totally normal, until now,
I only got this error when try to rebuild the project:

> Information:2015/9/23 15:38 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0
>   warnings in 5s 729ms Error:Android Gradle Build Target:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

How to determine where the error is? 
I also noticed that the R file is not generated, how to find the issue that cause the R file not generated?

I tried something like restart IntelliJ, Invalidate Cache, I also added --stacktrace in the Commandline options in IntelliJ Settings -> Gradle Android Compiler, there is still no stacktrace, and no use at all.

what should I do? I have no idea how to find the error and what caused it.

I'm using the newest IntelliJ Idea, v14.1.4.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621242/android-design-library-gradle-null-pointer-exception